# Can you have cross browser testing using Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, cross-browser, robotframework

I have a robot-framework test suite that runs all OK.

I have it running with pabot and selenium Grid, so parallel testing is all good.

My question is, can I run my test suite against multiple browsers without having to manually run the same scripts for each browser or duplicating my test suite for each browser.
Essentially, using a "Resource.txt" file to tell the test to instantiate the browser the grid node is set up for.

For example, in a TestNG project (Using POM method) I use the "if" and "else" methods to tell the test to use the browser that the selenium grid node is set up for.

Python 2.7
RF 3.0.2
Grid 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to do this is to use a variable to hold the name of the browser, and then set the variable from the command line

In your test case:

```
open browser  ${ROOT_URL}  ${BROWSER}
```

From the command line:

```
robot --variable BROWSER:firefox ...
-or-
robot --variable BROWSER:chrome ...
```

An alternative to setting the variable on the command line is to have your tests use a [variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) which dynamically sets the value of the variable based on runtime conditions.

Comment: Can this be done without the separate command line inputs? For example, all browsers set as a variable and have the test select the browser to match the node setup?

Comment: @Richard: of course. You will have to modify all of your tests to call a setup keyword. This setup keyword can do anything you want. Or, use a variable file that dynamically sets the variable based on some condition.

Comment: Ideally I would like to use the variable file  method that you suggest, that i can call in the test script. But I cannot see how this can be done using the keyword library. Can I use "if" and "else" as in TestNG etc or do I just have a resource file that instantiates any browser that I want to use. Currently my script has the variable  '${BROWSER}        chrome' and the keyword "Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}  None  ${SERVER}' (Server being the grid)

Comment: @Richard I don't understand your question. The variable file is written in python so it has all the logical constructs that you need. If you instead write a keyword that you call in a suite setup, robot has enough keywords to get the job done ("Run keyword if...", etc).

Comment: You are right, got myself confused reading that back, my apologies. But the "Run Keyword if" route is a big help and looks like what I am looking for.